# Change authentication method of FIWARE Business API Ecosystem

Tags: fiware

I'm trying to integrate the FIWARE Business API Ecosystem in a website that uses shibboleth as authentication system.

It is possible to change the authentication method so as to login with shibboleth in the components? Moreover what I'd like to do is login with shibboleth and stay logged when navigating to the business api ecosystem components.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Business API Ecosystem uses OAuth2 for authentication, managing the user information as provided by the FIWARE IdM.

Nevertheless, FIWARE Business API Ecosystem authentication is done with express-passport, in particular with an strategy called passport-fiware-oauth. That means that all the particular actions regarding with authentication are delegated to the library.

If you found (or develop) a passport strategy for Shibboleth you should be able to use it as authentication method